# DrawerLayout with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am developing android app containing side menu (navigation drawer). clicking drawer items I want to navigate to different pages. my Idea is to create one Activity and multiple fragments (I have about 30 pages to display), but I am a little weird about that. maybe using multiple activities is a better practice. whats a best practice of implementing app navigation like this one?

Comment: maybe you should rethink your implementation. You could use tabs in some places, and activities wherever appropriate.you could see other apps for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirement where you have about 30 pages to display

You should go with `single Activity - Multiple Fragments` approach

Advantages :

You have `less burden to handle callbacks of Activity lifecycle` because `fragments uses parent activity callbacks`. So, you need to handle only single activity callbacks. Instead if you use multiple activity approach, you have to work for atleast `onResume(), onPause()` callback of every activity

Comment: in approach : `single Activity - Multiple Fragments` there is less chance of memory leak, but we need to be sure to release all variables, array, unregister broadcast receivers in onStop() appropriatlely